# Form doesn't hide/show with *ngIf

Tags: forms, angular, angular-ng-if

I simple want to toggle the visibility of a form with a button that changes the visibility variable:

In the template:

```
<button (click)="ChangeVariable()">I'm a button</button>
<form *ngIf="variable">
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="personName"/><br>
</form>
```

In the component:

```
variable : bool = false;
ChangeVariable(){
 this.variable = !this.variable;
}
```

The problem is that it shows the form, but later it doesn't hide it. Ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error message itself explains, if **ngModel** is used within a **form** tag, the ***name*** attribute must be set, i.e.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="personName" name="anything" /><br>
```

And, second thing, define the value as below:

```
variable: boolean = false; or variable = false;
```

It should work!!